# Need helping adding circular radius to all my locations on my google map

Tags: javascript

So this is my first time posting, having large difficulties attempting to add a circular radius to each of my locations on my map. the locations are collected from "google fusion tables" and my question is can I "draw" these circular radius on my map through the javascript code. code posted below.

Many thanks in advance.

```
(function (window, undefined) {
var MapsLib = function (options) {
    var self = this;

    options = options || {};

    this.recordName = options.recordName || "result"; //for showing a count of results
    this.recordNamePlural = options.recordNamePlural || "results";
    this.searchRadius = options.searchRadius || 24140; //in meters ~ 15 mile

    // the encrypted Table ID of your Fusion Table (found under File => About)
    this.fusionTableId = options.fusionTableId || "1hBZWnWMHd1odTScLTi4lV3T3lWAtbK_C018MPVN0",

    // Found at https://console.developers.google.com/
    // Important! this key is for demonstration purposes. please register your own.
    this.googleApiKey = options.googleApiKey || "AIzaSyCMjlHSI4Z5zOq5q00bIQ9zwuG9mpPqlUY",

    // name of the location column in your Fusion Table.
    // NOTE: if your location column name has spaces in it, surround it with single quotes
    // example: locationColumn:     "'my location'",
    this.locationColumn = options.locationColumn || "geometry";

    // appends to all address searches if not present
    this.locationScope = options.locationScope || "";

    // zoom level when map is loaded (bigger is more zoomed in)
    this.defaultZoom = options.defaultZoom || 6; 

    // center that your map defaults to
    this.map_centroid = new google.maps.LatLng(options.map_center[0], options.map_center[1]);

    // marker image for your searched address
    if (typeof options.addrMarkerImage !== 'undefined') {
        if (options.addrMarkerImage != "")
            this.addrMarkerImage = options.addrMarkerImage;
        else
            this.addrMarkerImage = ""
    }
    else
        this.addrMarkerImage = "images/blue-pushpin.png"

    this.currentPinpoint = null;
    $("#result_count").html("");

    this.myOptions = {
        zoom: this.defaultZoom,
        center: this.map_centroid,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], this.myOptions);

    // maintains map centerpoint for responsive design
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(self.map, 'idle', function () {
        self.calculateCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
        self.map.setCenter(self.map_centroid);
    });
    self.searchrecords = null;

    //reset filters
    $("#search_address").val(self.convertToPlainString($.address.parameter('address')));
    var loadRadius = self.convertToPlainString($.address.parameter('radius'));
    if (loadRadius != "") 
        $("#search_radius").val(loadRadius);
    else 
        $("#search_radius").val(self.searchRadius);

    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", "checked");
    $("#result_box").hide();

    //-----custom initializers-----
    //-----end of custom initializers-----

    //run the default search when page loads
    self.doSearch();
    if (options.callback) options.callback(self);
};

//-----custom functions-----
//-----end of custom functions-----

MapsLib.prototype.submitSearch = function (whereClause, map) {
    var self = this;
    //get using all filters
    //NOTE: styleId and templateId are recently added attributes to load custom marker styles and info windows
    //you can find your Ids inside the link generated by the 'Publish' option in Fusion Tables
    //for more details, see https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles
    self.searchrecords = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            from: self.fusionTableId,
            select: self.locationColumn,
            where: whereClause
        },
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
    });
    self.fusionTable = self.searchrecords;
    self.searchrecords.setMap(map);
    self.getCount(whereClause);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle ({
        map:map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng (39.09024, -119.4179324),
        radius: 80000,
        strokeColor:"#00ff00",
        fillColor:"red"
    });
};

MapsLib.prototype.getgeoCondition = function (address, callback) {
    var self = this;
    if (address !== "") {
        if (address.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.locationScope) === -1) {
            address = address + " " + self.locationScope;
        }
        self.geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                self.currentPinpoint = results[0].geometry.location;
                var map = self.map;

                $.address.parameter('address', encodeURIComponent(address));
                $.address.parameter('radius', encodeURIComponent(self.searchRadius));
                map.setCenter(self.currentPinpoint);
                // set zoom level based on search radius
                if (self.searchRadius >= 1610000) map.setZoom(4); // 1,000 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 805000) map.setZoom(5); // 500 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 402500) map.setZoom(6); // 250 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 161000) map.setZoom(7); // 100 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 80500) map.setZoom(8); // 100 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 40250) map.setZoom(9); // 100 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 24140) map.setZoom(9); // 10 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 8050) map.setZoom(12); // 5 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 3220) map.setZoom(13); // 2 miles
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 1610) map.setZoom(14); // 1 mile
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 805) map.setZoom(15); // 1/2 mile
                else if (self.searchRadius >= 400) map.setZoom(16); // 1/4 mile
                else self.map.setZoom(17);

                if (self.addrMarkerImage != '') {
                    self.addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: self.currentPinpoint,
                        map: self.map,
                        icon: self.addrMarkerImage,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        title: address
                    });
                }
                var geoCondition = " AND ST_INTERSECTS(" + self.locationColumn + ", CIRCLE(LATLNG" + self.currentPinpoint.toString() + "," + self.searchRadius + "))";
                callback(geoCondition);
                self.drawSearchRadiusCircle(self.currentPinpoint);
            } else {
                alert("We could not find your address: " + status);
                callback('');
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback('');
    }
};

MapsLib.prototype.doSearch = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.clearSearch();
    var address = $("#search_address").val();
    self.searchRadius = $("#search_radius").val();
    self.whereClause = self.locationColumn + " not equal to ''";

    //-----custom filters-----
    //-----end of custom filters-----

    self.getgeoCondition(address, function (geoCondition) {
        self.whereClause += geoCondition;
        self.submitSearch(self.whereClause, self.map);
    });

};

MapsLib.prototype.reset = function () {
    $.address.parameter('address','');
    $.address.parameter('radius','');
    window.location.reload();
};


MapsLib.prototype.getInfo = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/' + self.fusionTableId + '?key=' + self.googleApiKey,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (callback) callback(response);
    });
};

MapsLib.prototype.addrFromLatLng = function (latLngPoint) {
    var self = this;
    self.geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latLngPoint
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                $('#search_address').val(results[1].formatted_address);
                $('.hint').focus();
                self.doSearch();
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
};

MapsLib.prototype.drawSearchRadiusCircle = function (point) {
    var self = this;
    var circleOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#4b58a6",
        strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#4b58a6",
        fillOpacity: 0.05,
        map: self.map,
        center: point,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: -1,
        radius: parseInt(self.searchRadius)
    };
    self.searchRadiusCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
};

MapsLib.prototype.query = function (query_opts, callback) {
    var queryStr = [],
        self = this;
    queryStr.push("SELECT " + query_opts.select);
    queryStr.push(" FROM " + self.fusionTableId);
    // where, group and order clauses are optional
    if (query_opts.where && query_opts.where != "") {
        queryStr.push(" WHERE " + query_opts.where);
    }
    if (query_opts.groupBy && query_opts.groupBy != "") {
        queryStr.push(" GROUP BY " + query_opts.groupBy);
    }
    if (query_opts.orderBy && query_opts.orderBy != "") {
        queryStr.push(" ORDER BY " + query_opts.orderBy);
    }
    if (query_opts.offset && query_opts.offset !== "") {
        queryStr.push(" OFFSET " + query_opts.offset);
    }
    if (query_opts.limit && query_opts.limit !== "") {
        queryStr.push(" LIMIT " + query_opts.limit);
    }
    var theurl = {
        base: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=",
        queryStr: queryStr,
        key: self.googleApiKey
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: [theurl.base, encodeURIComponent(theurl.queryStr.join(" ")), "&key=", theurl.key].join(''),
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
        if (callback) callback(response);
    }).fail(function(response) {
        self.handleError(response);
    });
};

MapsLib.prototype.handleError = function (json) {
    if (json.error !== undefined) {
        var error = json.responseJSON.error.errors;
        console.log("Error in Fusion Table call!");
        for (var row in error) {
            console.log(" Domain: " + error[row].domain);
            console.log(" Reason: " + error[row].reason);
            console.log(" Message: " + error[row].message);
        }
    }
};
MapsLib.prototype.getCount = function (whereClause) {
    var self = this;
    var selectColumns = "Count()";
    self.query({
        select: selectColumns,
        where: whereClause
    }, function (json) {
        self.displaySearchCount(json);

    });
};

MapsLib.prototype.displaySearchCount = function (json) {
    var self = this;

    var numRows = 0;
    if (json["rows"] != null) {
        numRows = json["rows"][0];
    }
    var name = self.recordNamePlural;
    if (numRows == 1) {
        name = self.recordName;
    }
    $("#result_box").fadeOut(function () {
        $("#result_count").html(self.addCommas(numRows) + " " + name + " found");
    });
    $("#result_box").fadeIn();
};

MapsLib.prototype.getList = function(whereClause) {
    var self = this;
    var selectColumns = 'name, description ';

    self.query({ 
      select: selectColumns, 
      where: whereClause 
    }, function(response) { 
      self.displayList(response);
    });
},

MapsLib.prototype.displayList = function(json) {
    var self = this;

    var data = json['rows'];
    var template = '';

    var results = $('#results_list');
    results.hide().empty(); //hide the existing list and empty it out first

    if (data == null) {
      //clear results list
  results.append("<li><span class='lead'>No results found</span></li>");
    }
    else {
      for (var row in data) {
        template = "\
          <div class='row-fluid item-list'>\
            <div class='span12'>\
              <strong>" + data[row][0] + "</strong>\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][1] + "\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][2] + "\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][3] + "\
            </div>\
          </div>";
        results.append(template);
      }
    }
    results.fadeIn();
},

MapsLib.prototype.addCommas = function (nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
};

// maintains map centerpoint for responsive design
MapsLib.prototype.calculateCenter = function () {
    var self = this;
    center = self.map.getCenter();
};

//converts a slug or query string in to readable text
MapsLib.prototype.convertToPlainString = function (text) {
    if (text === undefined) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(text);
};

MapsLib.prototype.clearSearch = function () {
    var self = this;
    if (self.searchrecords && self.searchrecords.getMap) 
        self.searchrecords.setMap(null);
    if (self.addrMarker && self.addrMarker.getMap) 
        self.addrMarker.setMap(null);
    if (self.searchRadiusCircle && self.searchRadiusCircle.getMap) 
        self.searchRadiusCircle.setMap(null);
};

MapsLib.prototype.findMe = function () {
    var self = this;
    var foundLocation;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            self.map.panTo(coords);
            self.addrFromLatLng(coords);
            self.map.setZoom(14);
            jQuery('#map_canvas').append('<div id="myposition"><i class="fontello-target"></i></div>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery('#myposition').remove();
            }, 3000);
        }, function error(msg) {
            alert('Please enable your GPS position future.');
        }, {
            //maximumAge: 600000,
            //timeout: 5000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }
};
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = MapsLib;
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(function () {
        return MapsLib;
    });
} else {
    window.MapsLib = MapsLib;
}

})(window);
```

Comment: 10+ pages is way too much code. Please edit your post to contain only the relevant parts of the code. See [mcve].

Comment: Do not expect a reply to so much code - this is not a debugging service. Try creating a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem you are having. Scroll down to the footer for "tour" and "help" links that help explain how to best make use of this site.

Comment: Have you considered using the OpenLayers library?  This library has extensive capabilities for adding and manipulating multiple vector layers to maps.